# Cannot get HTML Attributes from HTML file (C#/WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, html, winforms, html-agility-pack

I have the following code that I managed to come up with:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    using (var o = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (o.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            doc.Load(o.FileName);
    }


    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute att in doc.DocumentNode.Attributes)
    {
        label1.Text += Environment.NewLine +
            att.Name + " " + att.Value;
    }
}
```

But it's not doing anything. There are no errors, no exceptions, and it compiles and runs. But, as you can see, from inside the foreach loop, it is supposed to keep adding found attributes and their values to the label1.Text control, but it isn't. Nothing happens!

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By iterating over `doc.DocumentNode.Attributes`, you are trying to get attributes of the root element (`DocumentNode`) which is a placeholder containing your `<html>` tag (and possibly some adjacent nodes like comments and white space). Which does not make a lot of sense.

What are you trying to extract exactly?

Comment: Ah, now I see. In this sample I wasn't really trying to do anything. I was just trying to make sense out of things and see if I could just do SOMETHING. Since there's no documentation, and the only example code on the AgilityPack site doesn't work, I kinda need to guess everything. Object Viewer isn't opening for some reason so I can't use that to see how it works.

Comment: Then you should probably try first to iterate through nodes (`ChildNodes`), or play with XPath expressions. There is a **[good tutorial over here](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx#postadlink)**

Comment: @Lucifer - there is a documentation available here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/44954 but basically, the HAP API was designed to mimic System.Xml API. The Attribute concept is exactly the same.